# Access to methods in base class in java

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have this structure in Java:

```
class A{
private string Name;

public string getName() {
    return this.Name;

}


class B extends A{
private string Name;

public string getName(){
    return this.Name;
}

}
```

I create an object of class B and I want to access through that object the inherited method getName(). How can I do this? Is the method getName() from A overridden by B method?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to access through that object the inherited method getName().
>   How can I do this?

From a context outside of `B`, you cannot.

From within `B`, you can do

```
super.getName();
```

if its super type declares a `getName()` method.

In your example the method `A#getName()` is inherited and overriden in `B`.

---

Note that `private` fields are not inherited.

Note that fields with the same name may hide inherited fields.

Answer (score 0):

Change your structure to:

```
class A{
protected string Name;

public string getName() {
    return this.Name;
} 
}


class B extends A{ 
    public B(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
B myB = new B();
myB.Name = "Susie";
System.out.println(myB.getName()); //Prints Susie
```

You should place a setter for `Name` in class `A`. Also, `String` needs to be capitalized in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could just define class B the following way

```
class B extends A{
// no repetition of name

public String getName(){
    //you don't need to access A.name directly just
    //use you A.getName() since it's your superclass
    //you use super, this way A.name can be private
    String localVarName = super.getName();

    // do class B changes to Name

    return localVarName;
}

/*
 *rest of B class you may want to add
*/
}
```